# Entity Framework - Can you map the result type of an imported stored procedure to a custom entity type?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, entity-framework, orm

I already have an entity model in a separate dll that contains various objects that I need to use. I don't really want to create or duplicate entities using the EF designer. Instead I would like to configure it so that when I call a stored procedure it will map certain columns to specific properties.

I know you can do something VERY close to this using a custom DataContext in LinqToSql. The problem is you can't assign columns to complex property types. For example: I might have a columns returned that contain the address for a user. I would like to store the address details for the user in an Address object that is a property of a User object. So, Column STREET should map to User.Address.Street.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hopefully this link will help me. http://blogs.msdn.com/efdesign/archive/2008/07/18/using-stored-procedures-to-get-load-structured-data.aspx
Im surprised no one else has wanted to do this..

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here.

1. You can create a "Complex Type" and map that to the procedure result.  However, you have to do that in your EDMX; it's not supported by the designer.  Read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738472.aspx) for details. Note that Complex Types are not entity types *per se*, so this may or may not fit your needs. But you can find examples for [stored procs which use "Address"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716733.aspx).
2. You can change the visibility of your procedure to private, and then write a public interface for it in any manually-written partial class file which does the mapping that you want. Or just overload the procedure.